# Running npm global package as service with forever

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm, forever

I am trying to run my own instance of the discord bot available here: https://github.com/Gawdl3y/discord-rpbot. I have a Windows server VM set up and installed the script as a global npm package, and it definitely works because I can get the bot running correctly by simply executing

```
rpbot --token [token]
```

I would like to have this run in the background with forever (https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) -- however, when I try to execute it with the command

```
forever AppData/Roaming/npm/rpbot --token [token]
```

it crashes with the following error:

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\rpbot:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
         ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

I assume I'm not using forever correctly for executing a globally available command like this, but all the documentation I've been able to find is mum on the subject. Any help for how to make this work would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like rpbot is trying to execute *nix shell commands, are you sure it supports windows?

Comment: @jordanm As noted, I can run the package on the command line normally; it's only when I try to run it through forever that it blows up.